# In Scala, member of a class is not found when its instance is accessed from a list [Class]

Tags: scala, collections, types, type-erasure

I have a feeling that the problem I am facing has something to do with *Type Erasure* of Scala, but as a newbie I can't put my fingers on it. Need some help here.

First, the code:

```
    class C (val i: Int) {
          def mkString() = { println("C.i =" + this.i) }

    object C {
               implicit val cOrdering = new Ordering [C] 
               {
                   def compare (a: C, b: C)= 
                   {
                        a.i compare b.i;
                   }
               }
```

Then, I create another class which holds a collection of class 'C' thus:

```
    class  ContainerOfC [C] (s:Int) (implicit ordering: cOrdering[C]) {

               var internalCollection = new TreeSet[C]()

               def + (c:C): ContainerOfC [C] = {
                   this.internalCollection += c
                   this
               }

               def mkStringOfElems () = {

                   val y = this.internalCollection.toList

                   println (y.head.i) // <--- Problem here

                }

            }
```

This is what REPL tells me:

```
error: value i is not a member of type parameter C
                                    println(y.head.i)
                                                   ^
```

I have checked the type of 'y' out there: it is a List[C]. If so, why am I not allowed to access the 'i'? It is a construction parameter alright, but it is a *val* and hence, can be treated as a member variable, can't it be?

I have gone through a few of the other related posts in the forum, and Manifests and Typetags are possible ways out here. But, I am not sure if I need to go to that level for this simple use-case.

Comment: You know... I'd love to try to answer this, but your code is severely malformed and does not compile. Could you clean it up and make it complete and self-contained (including required imports)? (In particular, don't use braces not required by the language.)

Comment: @RandallSchulz: the code doesn't compile because, well, it doesn't compile and that is what _the question is about_. I should have added the 'imports' though - thanks for pointing that out - and the extra tabs are  results of hurried copying from REPL. I will keep that in mind when I ask the next.

Answer (score 2):

This have a strange and familiar feeling of "been there, done that".

How about you try to change this:

```
class  ContainerOfC [C] (s:Int) (implicit ordering: cOrdering[C]) { ... }
```

to this *without* the type parameter `C` in the declaration :

```
class  ContainerOfC(s:Int) (implicit ordering: cOrdering[C]) { ... }
```

The code you showed created a class and specific type `C`. When you later write `class ContainerOfC[C]`, that `C` is a type parameter that could be named by any other identifier. It is the same as defining `class ContainerOfC[A]` where `A` does not have any relation to the class/type `C` defined in the earlier code. In your example the type parameter `C` would shadow the name of the class defined earlier... The error message is indicating that `C` does not have a value `i` and that's because the compiler is not referring to the same `C` than you are thinking of.

Edit: just so you know quickly if we are on the same page without getting bogged down in other compilation errors, here are a few edits to make the code compile and using more commonly used indentation and brace style:

```
class C(val i: Int) {
  def mkString() = println("C.i =" + this.i)
}

object C {
  implicit val cOrdering = new Ordering[C] {
    def compare(a: C, b: C) = a.i compare b.i
  }
}

class ContainerOfC(s: Int)(implicit ordering: Ordering[C]) {
  var internalCollection = new collection.mutable.TreeSet[C]()

  def +(c: C): ContainerOfC = {
    this.internalCollection += c
    this
  }

  def mkStringOfElems() = {
    val y = this.internalCollection.toList
    println(y.head.i)
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for this. I have been through discussions on this topic in StackOverflow  but it didn't occur to me. Shouldn't the compiler give an warning in such cases? What's your opinion? Thanks on two more accounts: for taking effort to indent the code and for answering so quickly. I was restive. BTW, I tried to mention your name as @huynjhl but the editor didn't recognize for some reason.

Comment: @Nirmalya, yes I think a compiler warning would be great. I have opened a feature request for this a while back: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5691.